# ASP.NET MVC validation attributes and Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have mvc attributes on fields that validate on submit. Although these attributes are on these fields, I want to override their validation if I click a SaveDraft  button. Right now I try to disable validation of the field using jquery rules but the mvc attributes seem to override the rules. How can I make the MVC attributes ignore validation if I click a different button?
Here is an example of what I want to do onClick but it does not work.

```
 $(".btnsave").click(function () {
        $('#WizForm').validate(
```

{
            rules:
        {
            Title: false,
            Description: false  //dont validate this field onclick

        },
          }).Form();
});

Comment: Is this ASP.net or ASP.net MVC ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use following to remove all validation rules from an element

```
$('#Password').rules('remove')
```

To remove specific rule use

```
$('#Password').rules('remove', 'required')
```

And to add rule

```
$("#Password").rules("add", { minlength: 2 });
```

Finally to check current rules

```
$('#Password').rules()
```

> ***Note*** If your selector returns more than one element only the first element is used by rules method

Check out [here for more](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules)

Also make sure that you have [latest version](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). *more people got in trouble with IE and jQuery-validation-1.8*

Comment: may need to call $('#Password').blur() after removing the rule for the change to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I may just not understand your issue here but couldn't you just have the btnSave not cause validation?

```
<asp:Button id="bntSaveDraft" runat="server" Text="Button" CausesValidation="False" />
```

Comment: I use razor mvc. But I can use the cancel class to stop the button from validating but I need to be able to add validation to fields that the user has added values to. So I need to selectively add validation and selectively disable validation. The Jquery rules would seem to do this best but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

(Posting just in case someone else had the same issue as I did with MVC3 Unobtrusive validation library)

Beygi answer worked for me, but I made a mistake in declaring my elements.

I declared my elements with only and ID tag, and not with the **NAME tag**.  This does not work with MVC3 Unobtrusive validation library, as it requires the NAME tag.

```
<input id="firstName" value="" data-val="true" data-val-required="required" />
```

Needed to be

```
<input id="firstName" **name="firstName"** value="" data-val="true" data-val-required="required" />
```